# Retrieve APR data from Pancakeswap Finance [BSC]

Tags: bsc, external-api, pancakeswap

Is there an API by Pancakeswap Finance (BSC) to receive the APR for each farm and pools?

I personally don't wan't to calculate all APR individually by hand.

Comment: Is this about Ethereum? Please define pancake

Comment: no this is about BSC